# Error when add new host shard server

Tags: mongodb

I am getting an error when shard the existing collection. Can you help me?

This my error

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-23T15:11:05.331+07:00"}
 ,"s":"I", "c":"MIGRATE"
 , "id":23893
 , "ctx":"MoveChunk"
 ,"msg":"MigrationCoordinator delivering decision to self and to recipient"
 ,"attr":{"decision":"aborted"
 ,"migrationId":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"0d05a912-9ca1-4bf6-ba94-b9656b01da4d"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-23T15:11:05.332+07:00"}
 ,"s":"W"
 , "c":"MIGRATE"
 , "id":22022
 , "ctx":"MoveChunk"
 ,"msg":"Failed to clean up migration"
 ,"attr":{"chunkMigrationRequestParameters":"ns: exampleDB.exampleCollection, [{ _id: MinKey }
 , { _id: -4611686018427387902 })
 , fromShard: shard0000, toShard: shard0002"
 ,"error":"InterruptedDueToReplStateChange: Stepped down while persist migrate abort decision"
 ,"migrationId":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"0d05a912-9ca1-4bf6-ba94-b9656b01da4d"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-23T15:11:05.332+07:00"},"s":"W", "c":"SHARDING", "id":23777, "ctx":"MoveChunk","msg":"Error while doing moveChunk","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-23T15:11:05.332+07:00"},"s":"I"
  , "c":"SHARDING", "id":22080
  , "ctx":"MoveChunk"
  ,"msg":"About to log metadata event"
  ,"attr":{"namespace":"changelog"
           ,"event":{"_id":"mongodb-shard:27017-2020-11-23T15:11:05.332+07:00-5fbb6e993cfb07ec322470fd"
          ,"server":"mongodb-shard:27017"
          ,"shard":"shard0000"
          ,"clientAddr":""
          ,"time":{"$date":"2020-11-23T08:11:05.332Z"}
                   ,"what":"moveChunk.from" 
                   ,"ns":"exampleDB.exampleCollection"
                   ,"details":{"min":{"_id":{"$minKey":1}}
                   ,max":{"_id":-4611686018427387902}
                   ,"step 1 of 6":0
                  ,"step 2 of 6":2
                  ,"to":"shard0002"
                  ,"from":"shard0000"
                 ,"note":"aborted"}}}}
```

Comment: take a good look at the manual, and see all the requirements and maybe explain the steps you have taken

Comment: thanks on your attention, i was read at the manual and setup in mongo 3.6 and running correctly when add new shard server. but in mongodb 4.4 show error above.

Comment: You mean you mixed different mongo versions in your shared cluster?

Comment: What have you done? "add new host shard server" is different to "shard an existing collection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This done, on mongodb sharding version 4.4, shard server must be replica set althoug only 1 server in replica set.